# Application properties in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, properties, base-url

To maintain the application properties like BaseURL's, we used to create a `.properties` file and retrieve it whenever it is necessary in Java applications. 
In front-end angularJS application I can create a `.json` file and invoke it using `$http.get()` method.    
 Can I use angularJS `constants` for this functionality instead of making a `$http` call? Will there be any security issue if I use URL's in AngularJS constants?

Comment: there is *always* security concerns when dealing with client side JavaScript.  Clients can (and will) open the browser console and examine the contents of your JavaScript.  and even minification tools can't help with obfuscation.  If you are concerned with the sensitivity of your information, keep it server side.  Though you still would have to publish at least **one** URL in the client, the one to make the HTTP call to download the rest of your configuration, which one would assume is the same server as the rest of your data?  I'm not sure that trying to hide your URLs is a major concern....

Comment: Oh! I missed that point completely. So even if I take the URL from properties file, When I make a call to that URL, that is going to be  displayed in the browser console anyway. Thank you very much for inputs Claies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our projects we used to put all such configuration in one JSON file, i.e.

```
{
  "BASE_URL": "/myApp",
  "VERSION": "1.0"
}
```

and then, convert this file during build phase into angular module, i.e.:

```
agnular.module("myProject.config", [])
.constant("BASE_URL", "/myApp")
.constant("VERSION", "1.0";
```

and, finally, append the source code of the app to this config module with appropriate dependency:

```
angular.module("myProject", ["myProject.config"]);
```

There are [Grunt](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant) and [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant) plugins that can automate it for you.